# Newly posted answers loaded through AJAX don't obey sort order

Tags: support, voting, sorting

When a question is first posted on a busy site like SO, and one is viewing the question or composing an answer, new answers are notified by something like the following (don't remember exact wording):

```
A new answer has been posted to this question; click to load
```

If you click on this, the answer(s) will load right under the question, regardless of their vote order. For example, the first answer to this particular question had many votes, but the incoming answers loaded on top of it.

[image]

Is this even a problem? Answers are supposed to be sorted by vote order, but I don't know if they are supposed to rearrange themselves as they come in. Also, things re-sort themselves if the page is reloaded. But wouldn't it be better for them to auto-rearrange as well when votes change, in real time, and as questions are posted?

Comment: Why would they? The point in loading them is to read them, shuffling them around sorta defeats the purpose

Comment: _"Is this even a problem?"_, no. It's not a problem. It's quite good in some respects the FGITW doesn't necessarily win.

Comment: This has nothing to do about the FGITW winning. It's just about order of answers by number of votes showing up on a particular page.

Comment: @AndrewMao Just hit `F5` instead of the notification bar ;)

Answer (score 2):

It would be a non-sense. They *have to* appear first so that you see them where you clicked on "Load new answers". It makes zero sense to look for the answers all around the page (or even 2nd page if there are already too many answers.