# Order of answers with AJAX updates

Tags: discussion, answers, sorting

In [Newly posted answers loaded through AJAX don't obey sort order](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169529/newly-posted-answers-loaded-through-ajax-dont-obey-sort-order), the one answer indicates that the only practical approach is the current behavior of posting the new answers directly below the question.  But wouldn't it also be possible to post them in their proper order and to then *navigate* to the (oldest of the) added question(s)?

I've encountered a number of instances where the *newest* answer among two or more essentially equivalent answers posted around the same time is the one that is accepted. Since this typically happens soon after the question is posted, I'm hypothesizing that users are being influenced by the position of the answer directly below the question in an AJAX update, which under normal non-AJAX-update conditions corresponds to the *oldest*.

Answer (score 2):

Would it be possible? *Maybe*...

- If there's only one new answer, and...
- If the sort order of the other answers on the page hasn't changed, and...
- If there's only one page of answers...

...then this might not be horrible. But then, you *could* just skip the AJAX update entirely and link to `?lastactivity` too, which would do the same thing (and has existed for years).

Otherwise, you presumably want to just see what's new, and loading it right in front of you rather than jumping around the page (or to a different page...) makes that a lot easier.

Comment: If two answers have been submitted since a refresh, which appears "on top" in an AJAX update, the oldest or the newest? FWIW, I've only seen this "accept the newest amongst equivalent answers" occur with two total answers - never more than that.

Comment: IIRC, the newest (but I'd have to check to be certain).

Comment: Also, just to be clear, I'm not looking for options for myself or others to use. I'm concerned about the situation where the OP is not aware of this phenomenon and accepts the top-most answer in an attempt to be "fair" in the mistakenly belief that they are picking the oldest/first answer or perhaps without even being aware of any other answers.